# labeled tableView is not found in my View Controller or UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a View controller with 2 tableviews.  Originally I only had 1 and things worked fine but now I have to add a second due to some changes.

Basically, in XCode I re-labeled my first tableview to tableView1 and the second to tableView2.  In my delegate methods, in order to distinguish between the two tableviews I have an if/else clause like so...

```
-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   if(tableView == self.tableView1) 
       return @"Ingate Options";
   else if(tableView == self.tableView2) 
       return @"Outgate Options";
}
```

The problem is that tableView1 is not found in my view controller, but I don't know the syntax or what changes I need to make to let it see it.  I also tried self.view.tableView1 but it produces the same issue just in the UIView.  All I have done so far to these tables is change the 'label' value under the 'Change Identity Inspector' tab in xcode.  What else needs to be done?

Thanks

Comment: Show your IBOutlet definitions from that class.

Comment: I didn't create any... I just drag/dropped them in xcode.

Comment: At least you must have one or two `[tableview reload];` statements. What do they look like in your code?

Comment: ummm.. no I don't have any such line to my knowledge... I am using ARC if that matters...

Answer (score 0):

If you added your second instance of `UITableView` via IB, I suggest do remove that and create it programmatically:

```
self.tableView2 = [[UITableView alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
//do things... Note that this implementation leads to a memory leak, if not handled correctly (Use ARC or release it)
```

Comment: I could yes... then I assume just check for tableView2?  That would work, but I would still like to know what the problem is.  Just in case this happens to crop up again down the road.

Comment: To be honest, I don't have any experience with IB, but did you double check that you 'linked' your `UITableView` with the outlet?

Comment: The original table (tableView1) was linked. But that is more for finding delegates and data.  The error I am getting is specifically saying it can't find a table labeled 'tableView1' at all in my view controller.

Comment: Hmmm... As I already mentioned, I am not proficient in working with IB at all... So I won't be able to help you with this. I personally would suggest to do all this solely in code.